# Chicks - Girls, Cats - Boys?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, nouns, slang, history

The 1950's song [Fever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fever_%28Little_Willie_John_song%29) (covered, among others, by Elvis Presley) contains the following lines:

> Now you've listened to my story
>   Here's the point that I have made
>   **Cats were born to give chicks fever**
>   Be it Fahrenheit or Centigrade
>   They give you fever when you kiss them
>   Fever if you live and learn
>   Fever till you sizzle
>   What a lovely way to burn

How normal is it nowadays to refer to guys as *cats*, and where does it come from?

Comment: Even amongst [jazz] musicians, I doubt you'd hear "cat" very often these days. Certainly not likely to be used by the under-50s.

Comment: I thought cats meant as women, and to teach each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [etymnonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=cat&searchmode=none):

> Slang sense of "fellow, guy," is from 1920, originally in U.S. Black Eng.; narrower sense of "jazz enthusiast" is recorded from 1931.

Today, you generally do not hear the term used when referring to a man. Guy, dude, bro, man, buddy and pal are more commonplace today.

Comment: This answer makes you one cool cat.

Comment: Cool cat, looking for a kitty.

Comment: Can you call a female jazz enthusiast a cool cat?

Comment: @GEdgar: I suppose you could, though I'd think "cool chick" would be more commonplace.

Comment: Yes, you can call a female jazz enthusiast a cool cat.  I've played in jazz ensembles and the 'old school' guys refer to EVERYONE as a 'cat'.

Comment: Although OP has already accepted this answer (nine years ago), I would think that an answer would have to explain why the word "cat" should be used to mean "guy." Is it somehow related to another meaning of the word "cat"?